# Simple "limited user" MySQL frontend (WYSIWYG, for non-IT affine user) - stock or how to create

Tags: mysql, frontend

The aim of my database is to provide e.g. biosample data to coworkers. The database is relatively simple (few tables, several hundred entries, supposed to work for ~10 people within our institute).

I decided that a simple Excel spreadsheet would be possible, but dangerous, and I learned how to install and use MySQL e.g. via MySQL Workbench. Works nicely, I can do whatever I need using this GUI and SQL commands. I also found many other frontends/GUI that seem to work nicely.

However, all these tools I found so far seem way too complex for users, they will freak out if they see sth. like a command line, SQL command etc. They need a **simple WYSIWYG style editor that allows users to add samples, search for samples, and possibly correct data if found incorrect, but no administartive tasks or changes in DB structure.** A long time ago we had an MS Access database that provided this requirement, but I'd like to stay off MS Access for other reasons, it drove me crazy.

- Is there such an easy and intuitive "simple" user frontend for MySQL?
- Alternatively, I am happy for a hint how to set up e.g. a simple web page to display the data and provide editable fields
- MySQL may even be a kind of an overkill to our task, so I am happy for
  suggestions "in between" a simple spreadsheet and full-grown SQL
  database.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler database management system is
[Microsoft Access](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access),
which, as part of the Microsoft 365 suite, may already be used by your
organization.

Its relative simplicity might allow a shallower learning curve than MySQL.